# How to sort the object based on the value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a data like this:

```
export const keyOrders: {} = {
    "aa": { active: true, order: 0, val: "aaa" },
    "bb": { active: true, order: 6, val: "bbb" },
    "cc": { active: true, order: 2, val: "ccc" },
    "dd": { active: true, order: 7, val: "ddd" },
    "ee": { active: false, order: 4, val: "eee" },
    "ff": { active: true, order: 5, val: "fff" }
};
```

I am trying to push to array if active is only true and sort based on order value.

So far I have tried this

```
this.pdfKeys = Object.entries(this.dashboardElementsConfig)
                             .filter(([key, value]) => {
                                return value["active"];
                             })
                             .map(([key, value]) => {
                                return key;
                             })
```

I am not sure how to sort based on order number given.

Comment: What is the expected output

Comment: @MaheerAli I need ["aa", "cc", "ff", "bb", "dd" ] array result active is true and sorted by order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can folllow following steps.

- Get an array of keys using `Object.keys()`
- Use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) to 
  kets of all items with `active:true`
- Use [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort filtered array in ascending or descending order.
- At the end use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) to convert each `key` to `.val` of the value

You can first  all the `active:true` objects and then use  and `map()` each `key` to desired value

```js
let obj = {
    "aa": { active: true, order: 0, val: "aaa" },
    "bb": { active: true, order: 6, val: "bbb" },
    "cc": { active: true, order: 2, val: "ccc" },
    "dd": { active: true, order: 7, val: "ddd" },
    "ee": { active: false, order: 4, val: "eee" },
    "ff": { active: true, order: 5, val: "fff" }
};
let asc = Object.keys(obj)
                   .filter(x => obj[x].active)
                   .sort((a,b) => obj[a].order - obj[b].order)
                   .map(x => obj[x].val);
let dec = Object.keys(obj)
                    .filter(x => obj[x].active)
                    .sort((a,b) => obj[b].order - obj[a].order)
                    .map(x => obj[x].val);
console.log(asc)
console.log(dec)
```

Comment: Thank you how to do it asc or desc order

Comment: @nas I have added both asc and desc order

Comment: Sorry, I have to update question . I used Object.entries because I have to return val not key at end

Comment: Thank you very much I understand my mistake